# Windows executables with complete embedded debug symbols?

Tags: windows, symbols, dbghelp

Are there cases when a Windows executable (written in C++ with Visual Studio) can contain its full debug symbols? Or are the full set of debugging symbols contained only in its .pdb file?

Is there a way to configure building a windows application so that we can debug it without having the .pdb file?

Comment: How you configure building a Windows application depends, unsurprisingly enough, on your build tools.  Are you using Microsoft C++ compilers and `link.exe`?  .NET compilers such as `csc.exe`?  Classic VB?  Fortran?  Delphi?  C++ compilers from another vendor (e.g. Intel or GCC or clang)?  There is no magic option recognized by every toolchain.

Comment: I've clarified how the application is written.

Comment: I guess you've already read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format ?

Comment: I have not actually. So I guess the answer to my question is yes.

Comment: Oh, you can get it into a obj or lib using `/Z7`, but it still won't be embedded in the exe :(

Comment: It's not something I was looking to try. I just wanted to know if it was a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for your toolchain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info):

> The compiler's C7 Compatible (/Z7) option causes the compiler to leave the debugging information in the .obj files. You can also use the Program Database (/Zi) compiler option to store the debugging information in a PDB for the .obj file. The linker looks for the object's PDB first in the absolute path written in the .obj file, and then in the directory that contains the .obj file. You cannot specify an object's PDB file name or location to the linker.
>
> **It is not possible to create an .exe or .dll that contains debug information. Debug information is always placed in a .obj or .pdb file.**

This doesn't rule out debug information placed into a section of an EXE file by other tools... but Microsoft Visual Studio's C++ tools never do.

For information on placing debug information into OBJ files (possibly contained inside LIB static libraries) instead of a PDB, read [the documentation on the compiler option for Debug Information Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format)